# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to save the value from my component to firebase using service. But I am getting NullInjector Error when ever I use service. I did everything that was not the internet. Imported everything but it wont work. I already tried importing HttpClientModule, AngularFireDatabase but nothing works. I have tried to completely recreate the project by freshly installing everything. I have tried different versions of firebase and angular (currently firebase@7.24.0 @angular/fire@6.0.3). Nothing works.

This is my fireservice.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireserviceService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    
   }
   create(){
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated:new Date().getTime()
    });
  }
}
```

this is my app module

```
import { FireserviceService } from './fireservice.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BrainComponent } from './brain/brain.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BrainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFirestore,
    FireserviceService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){

  }
}
```

this is my compnent

```
import { FireserviceService } from './../fireservice.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'brain',
  templateUrl: './brain.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./brain.component.css']
})
export class BrainComponent  {

  constructor(private cartService: FireserviceService) { }
  addToCart(val:any){
    console.log(val)
  }

}
```

This is the error I get

```
core.js:6142 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FireserviceService -> AngularFireDatabase -> AngularFireDatabase -> AngularFireDatabase]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:38768:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:38935:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:38935:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:38935:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:32465:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:32469:61)
    at Object.FireserviceService_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:51081/main.js:280:159)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:39103:35)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:38924:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:51081/vendor.js:53004:33)
```

The site works fine until I add parameters to the constructor in the brain component. But as soon as I add `private cartService: FireserviceService` in the `constructor` in the brain component it won't even load HTML.
I am new to angular and firebase. I am trying to save the value in the firebase database. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for your question. If others are like me, they may see this error with obfuscated service names, so it's hard to understand `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_a14])[_a12 -> _a12 -> _a11 -> _a11]:`  I don't know why the error message is obfuscated like that but my solution was as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864088/1175496), that is to make sure all my services (and the services needed by the original services, etc...) use the `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})` syntax

Answer (score 28):

You can see from the error message that the dependency container is missing a provider for AngularFireDatabase:

> " No provider for AngularFireDatabase"

If you use AngularFireDatabase you need to import that service in app.module.ts in providers - you're currently importing AngularFirestore.

```
  providers: [
    AngularFireDatabase,
    FireserviceService
  ],
```

Comment: The answer states it needed to provide `AngularFireDatabase`, not `AngularFirestore`, which indeed was imported. 
So it was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 23):

Check in your service whether `@Injectable` annotation is as shown below:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Comment: And if you don't want the service to be provided by the root module?

Answer (score 20):

Import **HttpClientModule** into **app.module.ts** and add **HttpClientModule** to imports array.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to use Angular Fire Database but imported Angular Firestore Module and Angular Firestore in app module.

Replace AngularFirestoreModule with AngularFireDatabaseModule and AngularFirestore with AngularFireDatabase in app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireDatabase,
    FireserviceService
  ],
```

However, I will recommend to use Angular Firestore instead of Angular Fire Database if you are starting new.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

Comment: Thank you so much. After I followed your instruction it gave me an error saying "Error: ./src/app/app.module.factory.js 19:2850-2872
"export 'RealtimeDatabaseURL' (imported as 'i8') was not found in '@angular/fire'". I look through the internet a bit and found out I had to change the versions of angular and angular fire to a compatible one. I changed angular to 9 and angular fire to 5.4.2. It is working now.

Comment: I tried to replicate a similar code to my main project and now it is not working again. It is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685868/11135174),

If you are using libraries and add `firebase` as `dependency`, you have to keep both place with the same version

Meaning if

### MainApp

```json
"dependencies": { 
  "@my/lib": "1.0.0",
  "firebase": "7.22.0" 
}
```

### @my/lib

```json
"dependencies": { 
  "firebase": "7.24.0"  // <-- The version is higher
}
```

Then you will face the same error.
The way to fix this would be to bump the `@another/lib` version into `MainApp` from `7.22.0` to `7.24.0`.

*See the linked issue to see why you shouldn't import it into the `dependencies` but into the `peerDependencies`*

Answer (score 1):

I Has same issue. I fixed this by changing from

```
import { Database, onValue, ref, set } from "firebase/database";
```

to

```
import { Database, onValue, ref, set } from "@angular/fire/database";
```

in service. (Angular 13 & Fire 7.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

you should check if yo have imported the `HttpClientModule` since services usually uses it and I didn't see it in your code. Try it and give me some feedback! I had this same problem and I did solve it by importing the `HttpClientModule`

I have imported it in app.module like this

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // HERE

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule // HERE
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and also you should check if you have de `@Injectable` decorator with the `providedIn: 'root'` in the service class like this

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // HERE
})
export class SocialPostsService {
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing this error in angular 17 version
just remove all HTTP client module imports
and go to appconfig.ts file inside app file

```
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient()],
};
```

restart your application

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

In your `app.module.ts > imports:[ ]`

Replace this :

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
```

with this :

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFireDatabaseModule
```

Answer (score 0):

In main.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = 
{ providers [provideRouter(routes), importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)]};
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was missing this

```
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  ...
  provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
  ...
],
```

in app.module.ts